# Does mutationObserver on parent detect changes within iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have implemented a mutationObserver on parent page to watch an iframe embedded within it using the following code:

```
function testMutation(){
    console.log('test mutation called');   
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    var config = {
      attributes: true,
      attributeOldValue: true,
      characterData: true,
      characterDataOldValue: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    };
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
});}); observer.observe(element, config);
}
window.onload = testMutation();
```

Going through the documentation of mutationObserver on MDN, I altered the config to watch child nodes by setting `childList` property in config to true.

But when this is implemented, only changes corresponding to iframe attributes are being triggered. The mutationObserver does not grab node changes when navigating through iframe content having various nodes. Am I missing something?

html markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing iframe navigation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>iframe{width: 1px;min-width: 100%;}</style>
    <div id="testString"><h1>Following is from iframe: </h1></div>
<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://127.0.0.1:8080" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```